# how to have manage a prop in an html form in Vue.js / infinite loop prevention via computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js signup form that has a bunch of similar fields. My understanding is that I should initialize the values as props and NOT as objects or arrays (because they will be pass-by-value).

I am using a computed property with getters / setters. I'd imagine that when I set my computed property, I need to emit to the parent component the value. Is this (in general) the correct way to do this? If not, what would be?

Also (and here's is the real question), if I emit from my setter and catch in the parent component, won't this just create an infinite loop as it gets passed back down as a prop? Or is there some mechanism within vue where if it doesn't change, it doesn't get re-emitted? IE, does assigning the same value as passed down by a props cause a watch-getter to fire?

Like the proposed component in first part and how it would be used in second:

```
Vue.component('signup-input',{
  props:['placeholder','err','initialValue'],
  template:`
  <label>
    <div class='signup-font'>Company Name Within Component</div>
      <input @focus="err = null" v-model="tmpItem" :placeholder="placeholder" size="30" type="text" v-bind:class="{'no-margin error': err }" />
      <label class="error copy-error" v-if="err">
        {{err}}
      </label>
   </label>
  `,
  computed:{
    tmpItem: {
      get: function(){
        return this.initialValue;
      },
      set: function(newValue){
        console.log('here is newValue: ' + newValue); 
        // I emit here and wouldn't an infinite loop be caused? 
      }
    }
  },
})


var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#signup',
  template: `
    <div id="page-bg">
      <signup-input :placeholder="companyName.placeholder" :err="companyName.err" :initialValue="companyName.value"></signup-input>

      <label for="company_name">
        <div class='signup-font'>Company Name</div>
          <input @focus="companyName.err = null" placeholder="My Company" v-model="companyName.value" size="30" type="text" v-bind:class="{'no-margin error': companyName.err }" />
          <label class="error copy-error" v-if="companyName.err">
            {{companyName.err}}
          </label>
       </label>
```

Comment: Just an observation: I believe camelized props are supplied as dasshed attributes: i.e `props: ['initialValue']` => `<signup-input  :initial-value="companyName.value">`

Comment: I am curious to see best practices to this as well. In one of my projects I did it by passing `fieldName` & `fieldValue` into the component so I could watch and update the parent like this `this.$parent.fields[this.fieldName] = this.fieldValue` on change, but I wasn't happy with this solution.

Comment: Also instead of doing computed property, it might be easier to `<signup-input v-model="companyName.value">` and `props: ['value']` and in component template `<input v-model="value" />`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this. See docs for [.sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

```
Vue.component('signup-input',{
  props:['placeholder','err','initialValue'],
  template:`
  <label>
    <div class='signup-font'>Company Name Within Component</div>
      <input @focus="err = null" v-model="localValue" :placeholder="placeholder" 
       @input="$emit('update:initialValue', localValue)"
        size="30" type="text" v-bind:class="{'no-margin error': err }" />
      <label class="error copy-error" v-if="err">
        {{err}}
      </label>
   </label>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      localValue: this.initialValue
   }
  }
})

var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#signup',
  template: `
    <div id="page-bg">
      <signup-input :placeholder="companyName.placeholder" :err="companyName.err" :initialValue="companyName.value"></signup-input>

      <label for="company_name">
        <div class='signup-font'>Company Name</div>
          <input @focus="companyName.err = null" placeholder="My Company" v-model.sync="companyName.value" size="30" type="text" v-bind:class="{'no-margin error': companyName.err }" />
          <label class="error copy-error" v-if="companyName.err">
            {{companyName.err}}
          </label>
       </label>
```